# type '_StreamHandlerTransformer<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer<Set<void>, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some problems when I try to get some data from the StreamTransform

I can´t understand what is the proper data type here

Uncaught exception:
TypeError: Instance of '_StreamHandlerTransformer': type '_StreamHandlerTransformer' is not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer, dynamic>

```
import 'dart:async';
class Cake{}

class Order{
  String type;
  Order(this.type);
}

void main(){
  final controller = new StreamController();

  final order = new Order('vainilla');

 final baker = StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
       handleData: (cakeType, sink){
           print(cakeType); 
           if(cakeType == 'chocolate'){
              sink.add(new Cake());
           }else{
             sink.addError("No puedo hacer este pastel");
           }
       } 
 );   

  controller.sink.add(order);
  controller.stream
    .map((resp) =>  { print(resp.type) } ) //maybe the sour of  the problem type is here 
    .transform(baker)
    .listen( (cake) => print('aquí esta su pastel $cake'),
              onError: (err) => print(err) 
           );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type in your `handleData` callback.

```
final baker = StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (Set cakeType, sink){
        print(cakeType);
        if(cakeType == 'chocolate'){
          sink.add(new Cake());
        }else{
          sink.addError("No puedo hacer este pastel");
        }
      }
  );
```

Comment: I found  a  solution, but let me  try  your solution

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution  i founded

```
final baker = StreamTransformer<Set<void>, dynamic>.fromHandlers(handleData: (cakeType, sink) {

    if (cakeType == 'chocolate') {
      sink.add(new Cake());
    } else {
      sink.addError("No puedo hacer este pastel");
    }
  });
```