# cloud_firestore upgrade - Not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, ProductAnalytics>' of 'streamTransformer'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This error message is on StreamTransformer - unabling the app to access firebase data after upgrading Cloud Firestore packagae.

The solution might be to modify the Streamtranformer query into a variable
[type '_StreamHandlerTransformer<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer<Set<void>, dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686965/type-streamhandlertransformerdynamic-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-str)

I failed to do it so - can you please support.

> type '_StreamHandlerTransformer<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>, ProductAnalytics>' is not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, ProductAnalytics>' of 'streamTransformer'

````
  Stream<ProductAnalytics> getProductAnalytics() {
    ProductAnalytics productAnalytics;

    try {
      DocumentReference documentReference = db.doc(Paths.productAnalyticsPath);

      return documentReference.snapshots().transform(StreamTransformer<
              DocumentSnapshot, ProductAnalytics>.fromHandlers(
            handleData:
                (DocumentSnapshot snap, EventSink<ProductAnalytics> sink) {
              if (snap.data != null) {
                productAnalytics = ProductAnalytics.fromFirestore(snap);
                sink.add(productAnalytics);
              }
            },
            handleError: (error, stackTrace, sink) {
              print('ERROR: $error');
              print(stackTrace);
              sink.addError(error);
            },
          ));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }```
````

Comment: From the Flutter logs, what exact line is this being reported from, locate that line in the file then let us know which line is it, so we know where to include the type declaration. Also what do you want to achieve? more context will help with understanding how to solve the problem

Comment: I am trying to retrieve firebase data with streamtransformer. It was working in the previous versions..

Comment: As the [migration guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/) says "The migration involves adding a `<Map<String, dynamic>>` in numerous places". From the "`DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>`" in the error message it looks like you may have missed one of those.